# I can not compile Pillow in Windows XP

Tags: python, mingw, pip

I installed MinGW GCC, add the path to the PATH variable, create the file in the folder distutils.cfg Lib / distutils in my Python installation. I tried installing with Pip or download the source code and run "python setup.py install". I tried installing it with `virtualenv` and directly into the system as well. This is the log of Pip:

```
    ------------------------------------------------------------
C:\entorno\Scripts\pip-script.py run on 02/14/13 15:33:32
Downloading/unpacking pillow

  Running setup.py egg_info for package pillow

    running egg_info
    writing pip-egg-info\Pillow.egg-info\PKG-INFO
    writing top-level names to pip-egg-info\Pillow.egg-info\top_level.txt
    writing dependency_links to pip-egg-info\Pillow.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
    C:\Python27\Lib\distutils\dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'use_2to3'

      warnings.warn(msg)

    warning: manifest_maker: standard file '-c' not found


    reading manifest file 'pip-egg-info\Pillow.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.hgignore'

    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.hgtags'

    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'BUILDME.bat'

    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'make-manifest.py'

    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'SHIP'

    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'SHIP.bat'

    warning: no previously-included files matching '*' found under directory 'Tests'

    writing manifest file 'pip-egg-info\Pillow.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
  Source in c:\entorno\build\pillow has version 1.7.8, which satisfies requirement pillow
Installing collected packages: pillow

  Running setup.py install for pillow

    Running command C:\entorno\Scripts\python.exe -c "import setuptools;__file__='C:\\entorno\\build\\pillow\\setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record c:\docume~1\aaa\config~1\temp\pip-8kdxpq-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --install-headers C:\entorno\include\site\python2.7
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    running build_ext
    building '_imaging' extension

    creating build\temp.win32-2.7
    creating build\temp.win32-2.7\Release
    creating build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\libimaging
    c:\mingw\bin\gcc.exe -mno-cygwin -mdll -O -Wall -IlibImaging -IC:\entorno\include -IC:\Python27\include -IC:\entorno\PC -c _imaging.c -o build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\_imaging.o

    c:\mingw\bin\gcc.exe -mno-cygwin -mdll -O -Wall -IlibImaging -IC:\entorno\include -IC:\Python27\include -IC:\entorno\PC -c decode.c -o build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\decode.o

    c:\mingw\bin\gcc.exe -mno-cygwin -mdll -O -Wall -IlibImaging -IC:\entorno\include -IC:\Python27\include -IC:\entorno\PC -c encode.c -o build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\encode.o

    c:\mingw\bin\gcc.exe -mno-cygwin -mdll -O -Wall -IlibImaging -IC:\entorno\include -IC:\Python27\include -IC:\entorno\PC -c map.c -o build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\map.o

    c:\mingw\bin\gcc.exe -mno-cygwin -mdll -O -Wall -IlibImaging -IC:\entorno\include -IC:\Python27\include -IC:\entorno\PC -c display.c -o build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\display.o

    In file included from display.c:40:

    libImaging/ImDib.h:38: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'UINT8'

    display.c: In function '_fromstring':

    display.c:186: error: 'struct ImagingDIBInstance' has no member named 'ysize'

    display.c:186: error: 'struct ImagingDIBInstance' has no member named 'linesize'

    display.c:191: error: 'struct ImagingDIBInstance' has no member named 'bits'

    display.c: In function '_tostring':

    display.c:204: error: 'struct ImagingDIBInstance' has no member named 'bits'

    display.c:204: error: 'struct ImagingDIBInstance' has no member named 'ysize'

    display.c:204: error: 'struct ImagingDIBInstance' has no member named 'linesize'

    display.c: In function '_getattr':

    display.c:230: error: 'struct ImagingDIBInstance' has no member named 'mode'

    display.c:232: error: 'struct ImagingDIBInstance' has no member named 'xsize'

    display.c:232: error: 'struct ImagingDIBInstance' has no member named 'ysize'

    display.c: In function 'PyImaging_DrawWmf':

    display.c:761: warning: pointer targets in passing argument 2 of 'SetWinMetaFileBits' differ in signedness

    display.c:767: warning: pointer targets in passing argument 2 of 'SetEnhMetaFileBits' differ in signedness

    display.c:793: warning: passing argument 4 of 'CreateDIBSection' from incompatible pointer type

    C:\Python27\Lib\distutils\dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'use_2to3'

      warnings.warn(msg)

    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

    Complete output from command C:\entorno\Scripts\python.exe -c "import setuptools;__file__='C:\\entorno\\build\\pillow\\setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record c:\docume~1\aaa\config~1\temp\pip-8kdxpq-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --install-headers C:\entorno\include\site\python2.7:

    running install

running build

running build_py

running build_ext

building '_imaging' extension

creating build\temp.win32-2.7

creating build\temp.win32-2.7\Release

creating build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\libimaging

c:\mingw\bin\gcc.exe -mno-cygwin -mdll -O -Wall -IlibImaging -IC:\entorno\include -IC:\Python27\include -IC:\entorno\PC -c _imaging.c -o build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\_imaging.o

c:\mingw\bin\gcc.exe -mno-cygwin -mdll -O -Wall -IlibImaging -IC:\entorno\include -IC:\Python27\include -IC:\entorno\PC -c decode.c -o build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\decode.o

c:\mingw\bin\gcc.exe -mno-cygwin -mdll -O -Wall -IlibImaging -IC:\entorno\include -IC:\Python27\include -IC:\entorno\PC -c encode.c -o build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\encode.o

c:\mingw\bin\gcc.exe -mno-cygwin -mdll -O -Wall -IlibImaging -IC:\entorno\include -IC:\Python27\include -IC:\entorno\PC -c map.c -o build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\map.o

c:\mingw\bin\gcc.exe -mno-cygwin -mdll -O -Wall -IlibImaging -IC:\entorno\include -IC:\Python27\include -IC:\entorno\PC -c display.c -o build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\display.o

In file included from display.c:40:

libImaging/ImDib.h:38: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'UINT8'

display.c: In function '_fromstring':

display.c:186: error: 'struct ImagingDIBInstance' has no member named 'ysize'

display.c:186: error: 'struct ImagingDIBInstance' has no member named 'linesize'

display.c:191: error: 'struct ImagingDIBInstance' has no member named 'bits'

display.c: In function '_tostring':

display.c:204: error: 'struct ImagingDIBInstance' has no member named 'bits'

display.c:204: error: 'struct ImagingDIBInstance' has no member named 'ysize'

display.c:204: error: 'struct ImagingDIBInstance' has no member named 'linesize'

display.c: In function '_getattr':

display.c:230: error: 'struct ImagingDIBInstance' has no member named 'mode'

display.c:232: error: 'struct ImagingDIBInstance' has no member named 'xsize'

display.c:232: error: 'struct ImagingDIBInstance' has no member named 'ysize'

display.c: In function 'PyImaging_DrawWmf':

display.c:761: warning: pointer targets in passing argument 2 of 'SetWinMetaFileBits' differ in signedness

display.c:767: warning: pointer targets in passing argument 2 of 'SetEnhMetaFileBits' differ in signedness

display.c:793: warning: passing argument 4 of 'CreateDIBSection' from incompatible pointer type

C:\Python27\Lib\distutils\dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'use_2to3'

  warnings.warn(msg)

error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------

Command C:\entorno\Scripts\python.exe -c "import setuptools;__file__='C:\\entorno\\build\\pillow\\setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record c:\docume~1\aaa\config~1\temp\pip-8kdxpq-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --install-headers C:\entorno\include\site\python2.7 failed with error code 1 in C:\entorno\build\pillow

Exception information:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\entorno\lib\site-packages\pip-1.2.1-py2.7.egg\pip\basecommand.py", line 107, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "C:\entorno\lib\site-packages\pip-1.2.1-py2.7.egg\pip\commands\install.py", line 261, in run
    requirement_set.install(install_options, global_options)
  File "C:\entorno\lib\site-packages\pip-1.2.1-py2.7.egg\pip\req.py", line 1166, in install
    requirement.install(install_options, global_options)
  File "C:\entorno\lib\site-packages\pip-1.2.1-py2.7.egg\pip\req.py", line 589, in install
    cwd=self.source_dir, filter_stdout=self._filter_install, show_stdout=False)
  File "C:\entorno\lib\site-packages\pip-1.2.1-py2.7.egg\pip\util.py", line 612, in call_subprocess
    % (command_desc, proc.returncode, cwd))
InstallationError: Command C:\entorno\Scripts\python.exe -c "import setuptools;__file__='C:\\entorno\\build\\pillow\\setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record c:\docume~1\aaa\config~1\temp\pip-8kdxpq-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --install-headers C:\entorno\include\site\python2.7 failed with error code 1 in C:\entorno\build\pillow
```

It is not the only library with which I have problems, but I need to install this one.

Thank you!

PS: This is a Google translation Translatios, sorry.

Comment: Sorry , I don't have a good answer, but maybe this thread will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15142272/warning-not-a-valid-package-name-please-use-only-separated-package-na-es-i

Answer (score 0):

When I tried to install Pillow under Windows, I got a similar gcc failure, and the reason apparently was outdated setuptools version.

[Installation docs say](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation.html#windows-installation):

> **Python Wheel**
>   *Note:* Experimental. Requires setuptools >=0.8 and pip >=1.4.1
>   `$ pip install --use-wheel Pillow`

So, I [updated setuptools](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools#windows) (making sure I removed the old version), and pip install started to work flawlessly.

Comment: Thanks, but this problem could not wait and I did was rewrite my code thinking differently to work with PIL. I think it was the best.

Comment: @MauricioPanuncio: No problem; I don't think anyone would wait a year for answer. I just though this might help other people who suffer from this :-)