# WARNING: '' not a valid package name; please use only.-separated package na es in setup.py

Tags: python, django

I've come across a github project which I am trying to install and run it but I've run into some problems( https://github.com/andrewschoen/django-cms-demo ). I've also put this up as an issue https://github.com/andrewschoen/django-cms-demo/issues/2 .

The problem appears to revolve around installing PIL, if I understand correctly:

```
Running setup.py egg_info for package PIL
WARNING: '' not a valid package name; please use only.-separated package na
es in setup.py
```

I tried 'dropping in' Pillow by changing the line in requirements.txt to: Pillow==1.7.8

```
$ pip install -r requirements.txt

............
copying PIL\XVThumbImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\PIL

running build_ext

building '_imaging' extension

f:\python27\Lib\distutils\dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option:
 'use_2to3'

  warnings.warn(msg)

error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat

----------------------------------------
Command f:\django-cms-demo\env\Scripts\python.exe -c "import setuptools;__file__
='f:\\django-cms-demo\\env\\build\\Pillow\\setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__)
.read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\dni
r\appdata\local\temp\pip-cjnff6-record\install-record.txt --single-version-exter
nally-managed --install-headers f:\django-cms-demo\env\include\site\python2.7 fa
iled with error code 1 in f:\django-cms-demo\env\build\Pillow
Storing complete log in m:/pip\pip.log
```

I'm just starting with python and django , having come from php. I'm trying to set this project up on a USB drive, and I'm working on win7.

Thanks in advance for your thoughts,

Bill

Comment: PIL is not correctly packaged; there are some forks around that fix that, see [The problem with installing PIL using virtualenv or buildout](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2485295)

Comment: Can you put this in the form of an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PIL is not correctly packaged; there are some forks around that fix that.

From [The problem with installing PIL using virtualenv or buildout](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2485295), your best bet currently is to install [Pillow](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow/) instead; it's a drop-in replacement for PIL.

For Windows, use a [precompiled installer from Christoph Gohlke](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pil) instead.

Comment: could you please see my updated question, I tried to drop in pillow

Comment: @user61629: There is a typo in your `requirements.txt` now. `Pllow` versus `Pillow` (there is an `i` missing there).

Comment: Any thoughts on what to do next?

Comment: @user61629: sorry, still looking, I was confused by the warning before the error.

Comment: @user61629: Is this on Windows?

Comment: @user61629: Then I recommend you get a pre-packaged version from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pil instead.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to install that and open a new thread if nescesary - Bill

Answer (score 1):

PIL is not correctly packaged.

Its not an critical error, forget it..

Answer (score 0):

You need to rename the project folder/directory. Change the name to `django_cms_demo`.

I'd say:

```
mv django-cms-demo django_cms_demo
```

But seems like you're on windows.

So, as a totally unrelated topic, I recommend you to try Linux. I can't imagine developing a django project under windows.

Comment: I'd like to but I have to I'm often in a situation where I have to use windows, without admin rights. I havn't found a good linux I can use in this setting.